# Best way to encrypt a file with just password (no keypairs) that is easily usable/decryptable on both Linux and macOS?

Tags: linux, encryption, macos

I need to encrypt a file, which is a tarred/zipped directory containing important files that I am actively working on. It is crucial for me to ensure their safety by keeping multiple backups, including in the cloud. Naturally, I want to encrypt these files to protect their contents.

I am aware that I should use a robust encryption algorithm along with a strong password. I primarily work on either Linux or macOS for handling these files (with rare occasions on Windows, but that's not a significant factor).

Now I have searched how to best encrypt a file which is easily usable on macOS and Linux and there does not seem to be a clear winner. Zip format is said to be the easiest but looks like zip format supports weaker encryption and on top of that I have not come across a reliable method to support only the strong ones.

OpenSSL seems to be a little difficult to work with (I don't want to carry the keys everywhere). I thought of using LUKS encrypted file but I could not use it on macOS easily enough.

How do I encrypt the file so that I can use it on both Linux (both x86 and ARM) and macOS (ARM/Apple-Silicon) with just a password without having to generating a separate key pair for them? It would be great if I can just-as-easily open them on Windows too but that's not too important.

PS: I have scoured the internet and StackOverflow/StackExchange and some GitHub. Even ChatGPT failed at giving me something reliable.

Comment: You can encrypt your file with OpenSSL or GnuPG using a password. Both programs will create a newly encrypted file for you. GnuPG is the better and stronger choice.I would always prefer keys over passwords or password and key together, depending on the importance of the information.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's GnuPG, aka GPG.  It's not an archiver, but it does encrypt and decrypt files, including those created by archivers like `tar` or `zip`.  While GnuPG can encrypt/decrypt with key pairs, the `--symmetric` or `-c` command-line option makes it encrypt/decrypt with a password or passphrase (specified with the `--passphrase` or `--passphrase-fd` or `--passphrase-file` option).

GnuPG/GPG is available for Linux, MacOS (via homebrew), and there's even a GUI for Windows.

Comment: It looks like GPG simply allows me to decrypt without entering any password if I do not sign. It is more of a verification system than an encryption system. Anyways I have got gocryptfs and have decided to stick to Linux for all my work (VM on non-Linux systems).

Comment: @Vaibhav I didn't mention signing, which is not encryption.  The `--encrypt` and `--decrypt` options select encryption/decryption.  The other options for selecting passphrase rather than key for encryption/decryption, and providing the passphrase are in my answer above.  Signing is indeed a verification feature, not encrypt/decrypt, so it didn't seem relevant to the question you asked here.